# Animate a ListView unto the view

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve the effect of a piece of paper coming out of a slot with a list of items on it. I came up with one approach but as I am working on it I can't keep on thinking there must be a better way.

My approach:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/orderDetailListView">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Animation code:

```
final int newMargin = <some value>;
Animation a = new Animation() {

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin = (int)(newMargin * interpolatedTime);
    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
```

listView.startAnimation(a);

My question:

Is there a better way? I am not asking a suggestive question I merely want to know if there is a built in function of some sort that will make a view appear gradually from a set point.

[image: Image from yplan app]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want the animation to look like, it sort of sounds like a simple translation animation?

Comment: Take a look at this library: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations. Hope it can help.

Comment: I'm adding a picture from the yplan app it's the same idea. I'm not trying to move it so much as showing it appear slowly

Comment: are you trying to animate the items in the listview or the listview itself? What is the animation supposed to look like?

Comment: I don't mind it can be either or. It's supposed to look like a piece of paper coming out of a slot. see the picture I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to achieve a simple translation animation.  One way of approaching this situation is to use the [Property Animation Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) introduced in Api level 10 (and generously backported to api level 1 with Jake Wharton's [nine old androids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library).

A simple example could be the following

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(theViewObject, "translationY", -theViewObject.getHeight(), 0)
        .setDuration(2000) // 2 seconds
        .start();
```

sometimes, calls like `getHeight()` or `getRight()` etc, return 0.  This is because the view hasn't actually been drawn yet.  To accomodate for this you can register a callback to know when the view has been drawn.

```
// Listen for when the view has been drawn so we can get its dimensions
final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = theViewObject.getViewTreeObserver();
if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    theViewObject, "translationY", -theViewObject.getHeight(), 0)
                    .setDuration(2000) // 2 seconds
                    .start();

            // stop listening for updates to the view so that this is only called once
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh so simple! Coming from iOS I often complain about Android but sometimes I lay my sword and shield at it's feet!

Comment: One follow up question. How come this does not work when I put theViewObject in a LinearLayout? (Putting exact code in the question)

Comment: It's probably because the view hasn't been drawn yet, so `getHeight()` returns 0.  I'll edit the snippet to show how to work around this